# I am trying to read data from RFID. But the class RFIDEventListener is not getting called. Can someone help me out here?

Tags: java, rfid

The below code is what i am using to fetch data from RFID. But it's not working. By running this code, i am getting some output, but not everything i want.

RFIDEventListener is supposed to capture events and get data. Can someone tell me what i did wrong in this code?

```
import com.mot.rfid.api3.*;

public class TestConnect {

    RFIDReader reader = null;
    TestConnect testconnection = null;

    public TestConnect() throws InvalidUsageException, OperationFailureException {
            String hostname = "192.168.1.110";
            reader = new RFIDReader(hostname, 0, 0);
            reader.connect();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidUsageException, OperationFailureException, InterruptedException {
            TestConnect tc = new TestConnect();
            tc.getdata();

    }
    public void getdata() throws InvalidUsageException, OperationFailureException, InterruptedException {
            //Get power State
            System.out.println("Get power State: " + reader.Config.getRadioPowerState());
            reader.Config.setRadioPowerState(RADIO_POWER_STATE.ON);

            System.out.println("Get power State: " + reader.Config.getRadioPowerState());


            // Get Reader capabilities
            System.out.println("Reader ID: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.ReaderID.getID());
            System.out.println("ModelName: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getModelName());
            System.out.println("Communication Standard: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getCommunicationStandard().toString());
            System.out.println("Country Code: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getCountryCode());
            System.out.println("FirwareVersion: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getFirwareVersion());
            System.out.println("RSSI Filter: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isRSSIFilterSupported());
            System.out.println("Tag Event Reporting: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isTagEventReportingSupported());
            System.out.println("Tag Locating Reporting: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isTagLocationingSupported());
            System.out.println("NXP Command Support: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isNXPCommandSupported());
            System.out.println("BlockEraseSupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isBlockEraseSupported());
            System.out.println("BlockWriteSupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isBlockWriteSupported());
            System.out.println("BlockPermalockSupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isBlockPermalockSupported());
            System.out.println("RecommisionSupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isRecommisionSupported());
            System.out.println("WriteWMISupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isWriteUMISupported());
            System.out.println("RadioPowerControlSupport: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isRadioPowerControlSupported());
            System.out.println("HoppingEnabled: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isHoppingEnabled());
            System.out.println("StateAwareSingulationCapable: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isTagInventoryStateAwareSingulationSupported());
            System.out.println("UTCClockCapable: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.isUTCClockSupported());
            System.out.println("NumOperationsInAccessSequence: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getMaxNumOperationsInAccessSequence());
            System.out.println("NumPreFilters: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getMaxNumPreFilters());
            System.out.println("NumAntennaSupported: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getNumAntennaSupported());
            System.out.println("NumGPIPorts: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getNumGPIPorts());
            System.out.println("NumGPOPorts: " + reader.ReaderCapabilities.getNumGPOPorts());

            //GPI read config
            System.out.println("IS GPI port 1 Enabled? " + reader.Config.GPI.isPortEnabled(1));
            System.out.println("IS GPI port 2 Enabled? " + reader.Config.GPI.isPortEnabled(2));

            System.out.println("GPI Port 1 State: " + reader.Config.GPI.getPortState(1));
            System.out.println("GPI Port 2 State: " + reader.Config.GPI.getPortState(2));

            //GPI read config
            System.out.println("IS GPI port 1 Enabled? " + reader.Config.GPI.isPortEnabled(1));
            System.out.println("IS GPI port 2 Enabled? " + reader.Config.GPI.isPortEnabled(2));

            System.out.println("GPI Port 1 State: " + reader.Config.GPI.getPortState(1));
            System.out.println("GPI Port 2 State: " + reader.Config.GPI.getPortState(2));

            //GPO read config
            System.out.println("GPO Port 1 State: " + reader.Config.GPO.getPortState(1));
            System.out.println("GPO Port 2 State: " + reader.Config.GPO.getPortState(2));
            System.out.println("GPO Port 3 State: " + reader.Config.GPO.getPortState(3));

            // Gets the Duty cycle index
            short dutyCycleIndex = (short)(reader.ReaderCapabilities.getDutyCycleValues().length - 1);
            System.out.println("Duty Cycle Index: "+ dutyCycleIndex);

            EventsHandler eventHandler = new EventsHandler();
            reader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);

            // Subscribe required status notification
            reader.Events.setInventoryStartEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setInventoryStopEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setAccessStartEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setAccessStopEvent(true);

            // enables tag read notification. if this is set to false, no tag read notification will be send
            reader.Events.setTagReadEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setAntennaEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setBufferFullEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setBufferFullWarningEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setGPIEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setReaderDisconnectEvent(true);

            TagStorageSettings tagStorageSettings = reader.Config.getTagStorageSettings();
            tagStorageSettings.enableAccessReports(true);
            reader.Config.setTagStorageSettings(tagStorageSettings);

            reader.Actions.Inventory.perform();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            reader.Actions.Inventory.stop();

            reader.disconnect();

    }

public class EventsHandler implements RfidEventsListener {

    
    // Read Event Notification
    public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e){
            System.out.println("Read Event Signalled");
        // Recommended to use new method getReadTagsEx for better performance in case of large tag population
        TagData[] myTags = reader.Actions.getReadTags(1000000);
        if (myTags != null)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());
                System.out.println("Antenna ID " + myTags[index].getAntennaID());
                System.out.println("CRC " + myTags[index].getCRC());
                System.out.println("Memory Bank " + myTags[index].getMemoryBank());
                System.out.println("OpCode " + myTags[index].getOpCode());
                System.out.println("Get OpStatus " + myTags[index].getOpStatus());
                System.out.println("PeakRSSI " + myTags[index].getPeakRSSI());
                System.out.println("Phase " + myTags[index].getPhase());
                System.out.println("TagEvent " + myTags[index].     getTagEvent());
                System.out.println("Tag Seen Count " + myTags[index].getTagSeenCount());
                System.out.println("Tag Event TimeStamp " + myTags[index].getTagEventTimeStamp());
                System.out.println("getXPC_W1 " + myTags[index].getXPC_W1());
                System.out.println("getXPC_W2 " + myTags[index].getXPC_W2());
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();

                if (myTags[index].getOpCode() == ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.ACCESS_OPERATION_READ &&
                        myTags[index].getOpStatus() == ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    if (myTags[index].getMemoryBankData().length() > 0) {
                        System.out.println(" Mem Bank Data " + myTags[index].getMemoryBankData());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Status Event Notification
    public void eventStatusNotify(RfidStatusEvents e) {
        System.out.println("Status Notification: " + e.StatusEventData.getStatusEventType());
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think you should specify exactly what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change EventsHandler to EventHandler.

EventHandler Is used by RFIDApi3

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add:

```
reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(false);
```

Before calling `reader.Actions.Inventory.perform()` to get the tag data:

```
TagData[] myTags = reader.Actions.getReadTags(1000000);
```

You probably also want to set the maximum amount of tags read at once to something lower. Like a 100 is usually fine.